# Функция смайлов на php

Tags: php

```
function smiles($m_myrow_message) {
    if(!file_exists($file="../img/smiles/define.ini"))
    return false;
    $info_smiles = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach($info_smiles as $num_str=>$cur_str)
    {
        $arr_str=explode(",", $cur_str);
        foreach($arr_str as $key=>$value)
        $m_myrow_message=str_replace($value, "<img src='../img/smiles/".$num_str.".gif' alt=''/>", $m_myrow_message);
    }
    return $m_myrow_message;
}
```

в функциях не очень то и шарю, выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare smiles() (previously declared in X:\home\test\www\test\drink.php:168) in X:\home\test\www\test\drink.php on line 168
```

Comment: > в функциях не очень то и шарю

Может, лучше разберитесь в функциях? А то без них никак.

А в переменных шарите?

Comment: @bazaev05
http://zavu.ru/ZxR4pwg/

Comment: функция уже где то объявлена - используйте другое название функции

Comment: @bazaev05, а я готов поспорить, что функция smile() уже обьявлена в файле
X:\home\test\www\test.php в 168-й строке

Comment: @bazaev05, Учитывая !file_exists($file="../img/smiles/define.ini"), я могу в ней оставить только return $m_myrow_message.

Как же вам доказать то?

X:\home\test\www\test.php:168
X:\home\test\www\test\drink.php:168

Смените название функции в одном из этих мест или отключите к чертовой бабушке этот test.php

Answer (score 4):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare smiles() (previously declared in X:\home\test\www\test.php:168) in X:\home\test\www\test\drink.php on line 168

Это буквально означает, что в процессе выполнения скрипта, функция объявляется более одного раза. В данном случае она есть в **test.php** и **drink.php**.

*Почему-же нельзя 2 раза объявлять?* - При попытке вызвать функцию smiles() анализатор просто не сможет понять какую из этих функций необходимо вызывать.

*Как же тогда быть?* - Лично я, создаю один php файл (function.php) и там объявляю необходимые, часто используемые функции, и вызываю этот модуль 1 раз (хотя бы `include_once`) за исполнение.

Comment: тогда вопрос, сколько раз вы делаете `include "drink.php";`, т.е. сколько раз вы его запускаете?

Comment: > он отдельный файл

т.е. в браузере ты делаешь вызов drink.php ?

> там работает абсолютно всё, кроме функции

если у фатальная ошибка, как у вас остальное работает?

возможные варианты дальнейшей диагностики: 

 - поискать все функции smiles в ваших файлах
 - заменить эту функцию на echo "testSmile"; и посмотреть сколько в итоге выведится "testSmile" на страницу